# Creating a button in Java, causes getLayoutParams to return null

Tags: android, button, size, layoutparams

I need to create a button in Java. Below is my code:

```
 Button b = new Button(MyClass.this);
 b.requestLayout();
 LayoutParams lp = b.getLayoutParams();
 lp.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
 lp.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
 b.setLayoutParams(lp);
 b.setText("bla");
 b.setTextSize(16);
 b.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

I then add this button to the bottom of a ListView:

```
 getListView().addFooterView(b);
```

However this crashes, because getLayoutParams returns null.

Even if I create new  LayoutParams instead of getLayoutParams, i.e.:

```
 Button b = new Button(MyClass.this);
 LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 b.setLayoutParams(lp); 
 b.setText("bla");
 b.setTextSize(16);
 b.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

then the application crashes. Without setLayoutParams, it runs fine, but my button is not sized properly.

How can I size my button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I'm adding this button via ListView::addFooterView, it turns out I had to use the ListView type.

```
 b.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Using this instead of just LayoutParams resolves my crash. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this button to a view if you want to get `LayoutParams` from button. Or just create new `LayoutParams` and set it.

Comment: hi Pixie, thanks I just updated my question - I tried creating new LayoutParams, but this crashes my app.

Comment: It's not clear why your app crashes. So please provide a stacktrace from the logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

It's returning null because when you programmatically create a widget, it has no layout params!  (Until you add it to a view, then it receives defaults from the LayoutManager)

edit: above is referring to line 3 of your code

Set them like this:

```
TextView moneyTV = new TextView(this);
LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams(HeightParamHere, WidthParamHere, WeightParamHere);
moneyTV.setLayoutParams(lp1);
```

Edit2:  here's some readybake replacement code.

```
Button b = new Button(MyClass.this);
b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
b.setText("bla");
b.setTextSize(16);
b.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

Assuming you have defined myListener, this should work.

Comment: hi Eric, thanks - I just updated my question, please see it for code - I tried setting my LayoutParams using new, but it causes my app to crash.  The crash happens after a call to setListAdapter(adapter).

Comment: your app is crashing on lines 2 and 3.  you are requesting parameters that dont exist, hence null pointer exceptions.

Comment: sorry - I didn't update my question properly, I have updated the last code portion and this still causes my app to crash at a call to setListAdapter(adapter). Without the call to setLayoutParams, it runs fine.

Comment: Thanks for your Edit2 code.. I copied and pasted this, and it still crashes at setListAdapter(adapter). Without the call to b.setLayoutParams, it runs fine :s